# Protocols in Proxy Server Settings

Tags: networking, proxy, network-protocols

When I set **Proxy Server** in Internet Option->Connection->LAN Settings (Windows) which protocols does it support in which layers?

HTTP, HTTPS, FTP or...?

Download Manager also uses this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Web proxies forward HTTP requests. Some web proxies allow the HTTP CONNECT to set up forwarding of arbitrary data through the connection; normally this is only allowed to port 443 to allow forwarding of HTTPS traffic.